# Documentation for user-defined functions in Scilab

Tags: documentation, comments, docstring, scilab

I'm finishing a Scilab project for school, and I've added comments to all my function based on this passage from [the documentation](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/comments.html):

> Inside a function, the first comment lines, up to the first instruction or an empty line may be used to provide the default contents for the function help.

Yet `help` does not display the comments when I type `help myfunction`. Instead, it launches the help browser, on the search page.

Any ideas? Basically I'm looking for an equivalent of Matlab's "H1 lines" and "Help text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right instruction is

```
head_comments myfunction
```

When there is no native function named `myfunction` and `myfunction` is known as a user-defined one, indeed it would be fine to use directly

```
help myfunction
```

This wish is reported @ http://bugzilla.scilab.org/10785

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this function to convert comments to a help page:
http://help.scilab.org/docs/current/en_US/help_from_sci.html
and then compile it.